# How do I connect TypeORM to MongoDB? I receive errors while trying to connect

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

I have a NestJS and TypeORM project going. I am trying to connect it to my MongoDB database.

Here is the list of my MongoDB projects from the https://cloud.mongodb.com/ website:

[image]

The only name I can see for these is "cluster0" like here:

[image]

And then in my `.env` file I have:

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb+srv://roland:<myActualPassword>@cluster0.7llne.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
MONGODB_DATABASE=cluster0
```

and then the entrypoint to the application:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { SchedulingController } from "./scheduling.controller";
import { SchedulingService } from "./scheduling.service";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

import { Meeting } from "./db/Meeting.entity";

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: "mongodb",
            url: process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING,
            database: process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE,
            entities: [__dirname + "/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
            ssl: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Meeting]),
    ],
    controllers: [SchedulingController],
    providers: [SchedulingService],
})
export class SchedulingModule {}
```

But I see these errors:

```
[Nest] 16760  - 2022-05-16, 10:05:09 p.m.   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...
MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\jenfr\Documents\Code2022\TakeHomeTests\bluescape\bluescape\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:594:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
[Nest] 16760  - 2022-05-16, 10:05:42 p.m.   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)...
MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\jenfr\Documents\Code2022\TakeHomeTests\bluescape\bluescape\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:594:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
[Nest] 16760  - 2022-05-16, 10:06:15 p.m.   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)...
MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\jenfr\Documents\Code2022\TakeHomeTests\bluescape\bluescape\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:594:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

edit: I'm fairly certain my MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING and MONGODB_DATABASE are set properly, anyone know what else could be causing these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `useUnifiedTopology=false`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).